# 404 page redirect to homepage

Tags: redirect, 404, error

Is it possible to set up a 404 page, and after x amount of time redirecting to the homepage?

```
{% extends "_layout/_layout" %}


{% set metaTitle = "404" %}


{% set bodyId           = "404" %}
{% set bodyClass        = "404" %}

{% block content %}
    <section class="container">
        <h1>Page not found</h1>

        <p>What’s worse, a hilarious 404 page can’t be found either.</p>
    </section>


    <!--404 Tracking Google-->
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    if (document.title.search(/404/i) !== -1) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Error', '404', 'page: ' + document.location.pathname + document.location.search + ' ref: ' + document.referrer,,true]);
     }; 
    // ]]>

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use a meta refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">
```

With the number being the amount of time in seconds until the redirect

Comment: damn off course!

Comment: pay attention that the tag is broken: it should be content="5;url='whatever'"

Comment: good catch, feel free to edit answers when you see these errors :)